# livecode load URL theURL with message "myEvent"

Tags: asynchronous, url, livecode

I noticed that sometimes this code works, and sometimes my server doesn't see it

```
load URL theURL with message "myEvent"
```

if I start a fresh LC and run this code - it works fine, when I start debugging (other code) it stops reaching the server.

my guess is that if there's an ongoing async load - LiveCode wont allow a second one to run.
if this is the case - it seems the only solution for me is to restart LC - which is really time consuming.

any idea/workaround ?

Comment: There is a "resetAll" command that you can use to reset the internet library.